# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit" during pyspark collect_list() execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset of 50 million rows with about 40 columns of floats.

For custom transformation reasons, I am trying to collect all float values per column using `collect_list()` function of **pyspark**, using the following pseudocode:

```
for column in columns:
   set_values(column, df.select(collect_list(column)).first()[0])
```

For each column, it executes the `collect_list()` function and sets the values into some other internal structure.

I am running the aforementioned standalone cluster with 2 hosts of 8 cores and 64 GB RAM, allocating max 30 GB and 6 cores for 1 executor per host, and I am getting the following exception during execution, which I suspect it has to do with the size of the collected array.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

I have tried multiple configurations in `spark-defaults.conf`, including allocating more memory, partition number, parallelism, even Java options, but still no luck.

So my assumption is that `collect_list()` is deeply related to the **executors/drivers** resources on larger datasets or has nothing to do with these?

Are there any settings i could use, to help me eliminate this issue, otherwise i have to use `collect()` function?

Answer (score 0):

`collect_list` is not better than just calling `collect` in your case. Both are incredibly bad idea for large datasets. and have very little practical applications.

Both require amount of memory proportional to the number of records, and `collect_list` just adds overhead of shuffle.

In other words - if you don't have a choice, and you need a local structure, use `select` and `collect` and increase driver memory. It won't make things any worse:

```
df.select(column).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
```

Comment: Any particular suggestion for collecting all values per column without any of these 2?